# Pass a script argument in Azure DevOps pipeline which runs a Powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a simple `Azure DevOps Pipeline`

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure-DevOps'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: 'az-ps-scripts/session-07/vnet/vnet.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-RGNAME RunFmPp'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
    workingDirectory: 'az-ps-scripts/session-07/vnet/'
```

As you can see it has a `ScriptArguments: '-RGNAME RunFmPp'` and it runs `vnet.ps1` script.
But in fact, I do not know how can my `vnet.ps1` script access this argument provided by this pipeline.
This script creates a Resource Group for Azure, I would like tho use `-RGNAME` here:

```
$rg = @{
    Name = $RGNAME
}
New-AzResourceGroup @rg
```

But with `$RGNAME` it does not work, so does anyone know how can this script acces this argument from azure devops pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your parameter(s) in a `param()` block at the top of your script:

```
param(
  [string]$RGNAME
)

$rg = @{
    Name = $RGNAME
    Location = $vnetConf.Location
}
New-AzResourceGroup @rg -Force
```